# SQL Server Query with case

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am facing a problem.
I am not able to make a query which is a bit complicated but crucial for my work.
I have a view which looks like this :

```
dpt | status
94  | OK 
94  | Average 
94  | Average 
94  | Average 
95  | OK 
95  | NOK 
95  | OK 
96  | OK 
96  | OK 
96  | OK
```

I want a rule like:

- If AT LEAST ONE status of dpt is NOK -> return the dpt number with status NOK
- If there is more than 2 average for a dpt then return dpt number and the status average

According to the example posted the result should be :

```
dpt | status
94  | Average 
95  | NOK 
96  | OK
```

Comment: Reporting is one thing, but such business logic in the DB tier is another. Just saying', web apps are easy to make these days...

Comment: The rules are incomplete: what if there is only one line and the status is Average? What if there is a NOK and more than 2 average (rule priority)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation.  For your rules, this would look like:

```
select dpt,
       (case when sum(case when status = 'NOK' then 1 else 0 end) then 'NOK'
             when sum(case when status = 'Average' then 1 else 0 end) then 'Average'
             else 'OK'
        end) as Status
from myview v
group by dpt;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way that you can get the result

```
SELECT DISTINCT ok.dpt, COALESCE(nok.status,avgTable.status,ok.status)  AS Status
FROM myTable AS ok
LEFT JOIN (SELECT dpt,status 
           FROM myTable 
           WHERE status='Average' 
           GROUP BY dpt,status 
           HAVING COUNT(*)>=2) AS avgTable
ON ok.dpt = avgTable.dpt
LEFT JOIN myTable nok ON ok.dpt = nok.dpt and nok.status = 'NOK'
```

Answer (score 0):

I called the table cde:

```
select DPT,[status] from cde where [status] = 'OK'
AND DPT NOT IN (select DPT from cde where [status] = 'nok')
AND DPT NOT IN (select DPT from cde where [status] = 'AVERAGE' GROUP BY DPT,[STATUS]
HAVING COUNT([STATUS]) >=2) GROUP BY DPT,[STATUS]
UNION
select DPT,[STATUS] from cde where [status] = 'nok' GROUP BY DPT,[STATUS]
UNION
select DPT,[status] from cde where [status] = 'AVERAGE' GROUP BY DPT,[STATUS] HAVING
COUNT([STATUS]) >=2
AND DPT NOT IN (select DPT from cde where [status] = 'nok')
```